# Rename Windows folders in C++

Tags: c++, windows, rename

I was wondering if there was a simple way of programming in C++ the renaming of a Windows folder.

The program I would like to make would be something like this:

```
rename folder "Something A" to "Something TEMP"
rename folder "Something B" to "Something A"
rename folder "Something TEMP" to "Something B"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You need to use [MoveFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239.aspx).**

*I know it sounds funny but it works for directories too. :)*

Comment: The claim "need to use" should be backed up with evidence why `std::rename` can't be used.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Because he asked for Windows C++ only solution. So I skipped the standard layer and went directly for the API function. That's how we platform-specific people roll.

Comment: The claim "need to use" should be backed up with evidence why `std::rename` can't be use, even if you think it's obvious that one needs to use platform-specific functionality in order to get a platform-specific solution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I may be wrong, but I don't think "need to use" was meant to be interpreted literally as "this is the only possible way to do it".

Answer (score 2):

For the operation of renaming once, see MoveFile or MoveFileEx on MSDN:

```
BOOL WINAPI MoveFile(
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpExistingFileName,
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpNewFileName
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless your folders have names with international characters, you can in practice use the [C standard library's `::rename` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename), from the `<stdio.h>` header, e.g. as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>      // ::rename
#include <stdlib.h>     // ::exit, EXIT_FAILURE

auto fail( char const* const message )
    -> bool
{
    fprintf( stderr, "!%s\n", message );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

auto main()
    -> int
{
    rename( "a", "temp" )
        == 0
        || fail( "Renaming a failed." );
    rename( "b", "a" )
        == 0
        || fail( "Renaming b failed." );
    rename( "temp", "b" )
        == 0
        || fail( "Renaming temp failed." );
}
```

This works also with other OS-es.

Limitations / potential problems:

- The C standard does not explicitly state that `rename` also works for folders. I guess that's because C originated with Unix, and in Unix a folder is a file. In Windows the file nature of a folder is hidden with the ordinary means of access.
- There is no wide character variant of `rename`, so in Windows it can't in general handle folders with **international characters**, unless you use Windows API functions to first obtain pure ASCII "short names" – in which case why use `rename` at all.
- Modern Windows programs are usually wide-character oriented, which means a conversion down to ANSI character encoding, which is inconvenient.

Probably none of these issues are present for your use case, but if any of them are, then just use [the `MoveFile` API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as already mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Did you just says this function is not `WCHAR` friendly? And you ask me why I said he `needs to use`? You are aware that `*A()` function arguments are internally converted to `wide` before use these days. Any Windows dev uses wide characters by default.

Comment: @CodeAngry: Re "not `WCHAR` friendly", no I have not said that. In order to determine whether I said that or not, just read the answer above this comment sequence. Re "these days", it has always been so after 16-bit Windows, i.e. since NT 3.x cirka 1992. Re "Any Windows dev uses wide characters by default", well that's now, after I argued hard for it over a number of years. In summary I find your comment meaningless, as a comment on this answer.

Comment: Lame example. Unnecessary trailing return type specification. 'fail' may fail to compile, as it doesn't return value.

Comment: @Ajay: Please quote the standard regarding the requirement that a non-`void` function must return (I think you'll find that there's no such requirement, but it would be interesting if instead you did find one). Note that adding a dummy `return` statement is likely to produce code-not-reached warnings with smart compilers.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Oh! So, in your opinion missing a 'return' statement is okay, but using flashy `-> int` is fine! Happy coding then!

Comment: @Ajay: please do quote the standard for whatever your **opinion** is. this is the second time i'm asking you. as an alternative, if you're unable to make heads or tails of the standard (it's pretty technical), please provide a concrete example of compiler + options where this code fails to compile (I can think of at least one such combination), and then we can discuss whether it's standard-conforming or practical. please do not proffer unsubstantiated claims and general dis-information.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you use `boost`, you can use:

```
std::string name("old_dir");
std::string new_name("new_dir");
system::error_code ec = boost::filesystem::rename(name, new_name);
```