# Win32 MoveFile returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when renaming folders with subfolders

Tags: windows, winapi

My C++ application uses [MoveFile function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefile) to rename a folder, but given certain conditions, it returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. The conditions are the following:

1. The folder must contain at least one subfolder
2. Subfolder must have had previously opened before trying to rename.
3. Windows Explorer file manager Folder Option *Expand to open folder* is **checked**

#### Other observations

- Telling user to uncheck *Expand to open folder* option is not possible.
- **IF RENAME FOLDER MANUALLY ON WINDOWS EXPLORER I DON'T GET THIS ERROR**
- The folder may have international characters, so, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22152621/6327658), I shouldn't use [C standard library's ::rename function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename).

#### Some questions

- Why am I getting this error?
- Is there a better C++ function or workaround for renaming folders?
- Why renaming folder manually doesn't output this error? What function Windows Explorer uses???

#### Minimal, complete and verifiable example

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

void ErrorExit(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(dw);
}

void main()
{
    // Generate an error

    if (!MoveFile("D:\\folder", "D:\\new_folder"))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("GetProcessId"));
}
```

Adapted from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/retrieving-the-last-error-code

**NOTE** The folder have the following structure:

```
D:
└───folder
    └───subfolder
```

Comment: An access-denied error (5) means that "subfolder" is open, or some file that's in this tree is open. If a handle for "folder" itself were open without delete-access sharing, then it would be a sharing-violation error (32). See [`NtSetInformationFile`: `FileRenameInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_rename_information): "a directory cannot be renamed if it or any of its subdirectories contains a file that has open handles".

Comment: BTW, for Unicode this call should be using wide-character strings, e.g. `MoveFileW(L"D:\\folder", L"D:\\new_folder")`.

Comment: @ErykSun I see. But I get this error when I use `MoveFile`, whereas when I manually rename it, it doesn't. What is the reason behind it? Why is Explorer still able to rename files with open handles?

Comment: Explorer cannot. Open CMD and execute `cd /d D:\folder\subfolder`. Now try to rename "D:\folder" in Explorer. It will fail.

Comment: @ErykSun, i think, he means when open the folder "folder" using explorer, why he is able to opne an new explorer to rename it.

Comment: @ErykSun In my situation I am not explicitly inside `subfolder`. What I mean, is that `MoveFile` fails to rename, whereas renaming manually, it doesn't. Maybe this could mean that the issue is not an open handle, right? Indeed, if `subfolder` was locked I wouldn't be able to rename it, but for some reason I still can!

Comment: The shell may be smart enough to release the handle to allow the rename to proceed. Try `SHFileOperation` instead.

Comment: Within Explorer, and possibly across processes that are using the shell API, it may be the case that the shell is aware of its own open handles and can close them intelligently to allow a rename to succeed. But at the level of the kernel, this limit on renaming directories is written in stone. Even with the new POSIX semantics provided by `FileRenameInfoEx`, we cannot get around this limit.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter I used [SHFileOperationA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationa) and it seems to be working now.

Comment: @yellow01, except it still won't work if anything other than Explorer has handle open for any files in the tree or has any subdirectory open as its working directory. Users simply have to be aware of this behavior -- and close out whichever programs or shells are preventing the operation from succeeding.

Comment: @ErykSun Thank you for clearing it out. So maybe it is problem with Explorer? Because this happens when I open `subfolder` with `Expand to open folder` option **checked**. Even after closing `subfolder` it returns an error. My assumption is that this option leaves an open handle somewhere...

Comment: The option is not just "Expand to open folder"; it's "Navigation pane: Expand to open folder". Use Process Explorer to view the handles in explorer.exe. When expanding a directory in the navigation pane, even manually, it opens one or more handles for the directory that remain open (probably to watch directory changes) until the Explorer window is closed.